# Is there any way to know that FileSystemInfo.Refresh failed?

Tags: c#, ntfs, file-access, access-rights, file-attributes

It seems that [`FileSystemInfo.Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) requires specific rights on the file even though I can't find anything about it in the documentation. I suspect it requires write access to properly work.

Is there a way to check whether a call to that method failed? It doesn't throw any exception even though it did nothing while it should have. I could check the rights available for the file (and do something different for read-only files) but I would ideally want to handle the general case.

### Some context:

I wrote a piece of software that tracks log files written by another software. I use an instance of [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to listen to the file system changes. I noticed that even though the log file is modified by the third party software, the [`Changed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx) event is not triggered and the "Date modified" showed in the file explorer was not updated either.

I then discovered that opening the log file (in notepad for instance) forced the timestamp update (and subsequently triggered the `Changed` event of my `FileSystemWatcher`).

I concluded that the third party was updating logs with some sort of stream that was not changing the last modified timestamp (probably never closing the stream? I'm not sure how this is achieved). Opening the log file manually would basically refresh the file system information about the file, which would let my code know an update happened.

The solution I found was to schedule a periodic call to [`FileSystemInfo.Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) on the files I was monitoring (like every 2 seconds). If the file wasn't changed, nothing would happen (as expected) but if the third party appended lines then my `FileSystemWatcher` would raise the `Changed` event.

It worked very well (doesn't look pretty though) except that some users reported that it doesn't do the trick (if they opened the log file in notepad, the log watching process would catch up).

Comment: Does `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` after a failed call give you anything? You might also be interested in the [source for `Refresh`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesysteminfo.cs,1c7b7d54ada1ef87) (click on the method it calls to navigate to its source) - it might give some hints as to how the Refresh method behaves.

Comment: Seems like the interesting code is in [`Win32Native.GetFileAttributesEx`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,6ad7469366437f66) which isn't open-sourced as far as I know. I'll try the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` when I'll get the occasion, thanks for the idea :)

Comment: That's a Windows API function from `kernel32.dll` which is called via Pinvoke: [`GetFileAttributesEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946(v=vs.85).aspx)